# DataGridViewCell Type mismatch, when GetType().Name matches?

Tags: c#, datagridview, equality

When iterating over a collection of `DataGridViewCell`s in a `DataGridViewRow`, I was testing for equality of a specific cell like so:

```
var transactionLogId = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;
if (dgvRow.Cells[0].Value == transactionLogId) {
    // Snip
}
```

And to my dismay, it never entered the nested block. Though both equal the same (`5177518`), and both `dgvRow.Cells[0].Value.GetType().Name` and `transactionLogId.GetType().Name` are `Int64`, it doesn't work unless I append a `.ToString()` to both sides of the equality check.

Curious as to what I'm missing here. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operators are static calls, which means that overload resolution will resolve based strictly on the operand's compile time types.

In your case, overload resolution is resolving to the following operator overload:

```
==(object, object)
```

because those are the *compile time* types of the operands. The `==` for objects simply performs a reference equality check, that is, if both objects are the same object, which they clearly are not.

The same happens in the following code:

```
object o1 = 1;
object o2 = 1;
var equal = o1 == o2; //false
```

Using `Equals` in this case is the correct thing to do, because it is a virtual call and it will therefore resolve to the runtime type of the callee and give you the correct result.

Then why does this work when you call `ToString()` on both operands? Simply because the overload resolution resolves to the `==(string, string)` overload implented in the `string` class which performs value equality.

**UPDATE**

Reading comments by [Machine Learning](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6298965/machine-learning) there seems to be a misunderstanding concerning the reason why `==` is returning `false` in the OP's code. I want to clarify that boxing has nothing to do with it; consider the following example:

```
var str1 = "a";
var str2 = 'a'.ToString(); //to avoid string interning by the compiler.
var equals = str1 == str2; //true
object o1 = str1;
object o2 = str2;
equals = o1 == o2; //false
```

The observed behavior is exactly the same and there is no boxing/unboxing happening here.

Comment: Then why do both `dgvRow.Cells[0].Value.GetType().Name` and `transactionLogId.GetType().Name` return `Int64`?

Comment: @The1nk Because `GetType` returns the runtime type of the object, that is, the real type of the object itself, not the type of reference you happen to have pointing to it.

Comment: `Cells[0]` is accessing the `DataGridViewCellCollection` as an `IList` ... so using an indexer `object IList.this[int index]` ... then yes, that'll box the value

Comment: @MachineLearning Yes. And? I've updated the answer, Please read and explain what boxing has to do with anything here.

Comment: @InBetween your update is something *per se* formally correct, but it does **not** describe what is happening in the case in the question, because o1.GetType() from your update is not Int64 as the object in the real question. The point is that, as per my previous comment, boxing is present in the OP case (with Cells[0]) hence the == operator returns false.

Comment: @MachineLearning No! `==` returns `false` *because overload resolution chooses the `==(object, object)` overload* which is equivalent to calling `object.ReferenceEquals(object, object)`. Boxing, again, is irrelevant. But nevermind, I've wasted enough time and effort trying to make you understand. I truely rest my case this time.

Answer (score 1):

They are both **boxed** values so the == operator will never be true.

GetType returns the type of the corresponding unboxed instances anyway.

You need to use Equals.

Comment: You can also check this simple [counter proof online](http://rextester.com/MXUR57889): look at what happens to the types and the comparison of boxed int

Comment: boxing is relevant. In fact look at [this](http://rextester.com/JIQUE1997) without boxing. We are speaking of value types (int)

Comment: No idea why my previous comment disappeared...anyway, boxing is *not* relevant: `object o = "hello"; object i = new string (new[] { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' });bool equal = o == i;  bool e = o.Equals(i);` The `==` will fail and there is no boxing at all here.

Comment: The second `string` constructor is done that way simply to avoid string interning, which *would* make `==` return `true` because you'd be comparing the same reference.

Comment: @InBetween Again. The question is about two operands of type GetType().Name are Int64 hence the dismay (you are speaking of reference type that would generate no dismay): in this situation boxing is relevant

Comment: I'm sorry I dont agree. Your answer is mislieading, period. The equality check is failing simply due to how the resolution algorithm works, it has absolutely nothing to do with boxing. Yes, the longs are boxed....and? It is not relevant as to why `==` returns `false` which is the question the OP is asking.

Comment: @InBetween if int are not boxed the == returns true. Period.

Comment: Yes. And? My dog wags his tail when I pet him. I cut off my dog's tail. Now he doesn't wag his tail. My dog doesn't feel my petting without his tail. You are completely misunderstanding the reason why `==` returns `false`. Just because the behavior is reproducable with boxed types doesn't mean boxing is the root cause. Your answer is impying a causality between the observed behavior and boxing that is totally false and therefore misleading. I close my case, there is no point arguing anymore.